QNetworkAccessManager make another request after response
I have a QNetworkAccessManager instance
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html
 m_network = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
 connect(m_network, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &LabelEntry::on_finished);

that requests an URL.
example : http://100.36.4.152/index.html
the response is obtained in a QLabel class and in it I extract this URL, like this
void LabelEntry::on_finished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
  QNetworkRequest request = reply->request();
  QUrl url = request.url();
  QString path = url.path();
  QString url_path = url.url();
  QString url_main = url_path.remove(path);

  QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
  QString html = QString(data);

this prints for url_main
http://100.36.4.152
and variable 'html' has the HTML buffer
Next, I am going to extract the HTML tags from this buffer (irrelevant how to do it for this);
http://100.36.4.152/index.html
I obtained, that the HTML has an image tag in it, for example
icons/ubuntu-logo.png
so, the complete URL of this image is
http://100.36.4.152/icons/ubuntu-logo.png
Now, I need to get this image.
Question , what would be the best way to do it?
This was already obtained in a QNetworkAccessManager  instance, so, one way, would be to define yet another for this request ? and where to define and call it, from the  Qt frameworkt?
locally from this class (LabelEntry), or define  another class for the new request ?
Gracias

The first bit of your function is equivalent to url.setPath("/")

As for your other questions: yes, try to reuse QNetworkAccessManagers if possible, and hook up the QNetworkRequest::finished signal to your function instead so it only triggers for that kind of request instead of every request.

The approach for accessing the base url and following path is wrong and unreliable, as it's based on assumptions: most importantly, that the image path is relative to the root host. A more accurate approach should retrieve the new path by using resolved() of the source QUrl (possibly considering the <base> tag of the HTML, if present). That said, as written above, just reuse the manager by creating another request with the new url: the suggested practice is to use one, unique, application wide ("global") instance of QNetworkAccessManager.
